# want to print a series of string in excel using python

Tags: python, excel

I would like to print a series in my excel which goes like

*OUTPUT*

```
Data Set 1 copy.jpg

Data Set 2 copy.jpg
```

This is the code that I have written:

```
import itertools
import xlsxwriter

book = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'E:\license8.xlsx')
sh = book.add_worksheet()
a = 1

for a in range (1,1320):
    ch = 'Data Set '+ a +' copy.jpg'
    sh.write(a,0,ch)
    a = a+1
book.close()
```

but it does not create any excel file after i run this code.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
You don't get any output because your program has a run-time fault that you failed to include in your question.  You also make an invalid change to your loop index, which will damage your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there is an error in your code. Below are the error and corrected code -

> You cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

```py
#erroneous line of code
ch = 'Data Set '+ a +' copy.jpg'

#use below code instead
ch = 'Data Set {} copy.jpg'.format(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also change `a` to `str()` for that concatenation:

```
ch = 'Data Set ' + str(a) + ' copy.jpg'
```